# Prove identity for p-adic rationals

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm a bit stuck with this proof question: Let $p$ be a prime number. Every rational $r$ can be uniquely written as $r = p^n  \frac{a}{b}$ where $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$.
Let $|r|_p = p^{-n}$ be the p-adic norm.

Show that:

$$|r_1-r_2|_p < |r_2|_p \implies |r_1|_p = |r_2|_p$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please click on edit to see how it is easy to get mathjax formulas.

Comment: For your question, simply write $r_i=p^{n_i}\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and see what you get for $r_1-r_2$

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any non-Archimedian norm. Cf Koblitz, *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta Functions* (p5).
Here's the argument:

$\lVert r_1 \rVert_p = \lVert (r_1 -r_2) - r_2 \rVert_p \leq max(\lVert r_1- r_2 \rVert_p , \lVert r_2 \rVert_p) = \lVert r_2 \rVert_p$, by assumption. So $\rVert r_1 \lVert_p \leq \rVert r_2 \lVert_p$.

Using $\Vert r_2 \rVert_p \leq max(\lVert r_2-r_1 \rVert_p, \lVert r_1 \rVert_p)$, we must have $\lVert r_2- r_1 \rVert_p < \lVert r_1 \rVert_p$ to avoid contraditing the assumption. Therefore the argument is symmetric in $r_1$ and $r_2$ and we conclude $\lVert r_1\rVert_p = \lVert r_2\rVert_p$.